# PyDev: cannot disable autopep8

Tags: pydev

Un-checking 'use autopep8.py for code formatting' in Window->Preferences->PyDev->Editor->Code Style->Code Formatter will only last for the current session. When I restart Eclipse it will be set on again.

Adding 'FORMAT_WITH_AUTOPEP8=false' to org.python.pydev.prefs doesn't help, on the next occasion it gets overwritten with FORMAT_WITH_AUTOPEP8=true'

Comment: Actually, what bothers me in 'autopep8' is the automatic split of long lines:80 (or 90) is too short for me, and  the split is not always looking good. I'm fine with pylint flagging me the long line first, and then split it by hand (or not at all ..)

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the following:

1. Start Eclipse
2. Open the error log view and clear existing entries
3. Change that setting
4. Exit Eclipse
5. Start Eclipse again -- at this point, do you have some error in your error log view?

Another thing: if you point to a new workspace, does it work?

---

**Edit**: Besides the setting in the workspace, PyDev can also save settings to a **project** or to the **user settings**, so, this setting is probably being set to a different place in your use case (the fact that a new workspace keeps this setting corroborates with that).

In the Code formatter preferences page, you can click the **Open Settings** and then select to open the settings for your user or for a given project.

Comment: Yes, but the errors pertain to the missing new/not removed old Python interpreters only. No sign of PEP-8 ...
I tried the new 'workspace': it behaves exactly the same: autopep8 is always set. And it complains about the missing interpreters: this corroborates with my idea that there must be a 'hidden' persistence that PyDev looks into ...

Comment: Just edited based on that info (the setting is probably being inherited from a project, or from the user setting -- the one in the project gets top priority resolving it, then the user setting and at last the one in the workspace... the buttons: Save to, Show from and Open Location may be used to see the settings from other places and to save to those too).

Comment: Never saved a PyDev setting to a particular project: I can actuall only find a single.yaml in my fork of PyDev (from gtihub) ...

Comment: Humm, the default is *not* having autopep8 enabled, so, can you try double-checking it in the project and in the user settings?

Comment: I only have the _Workspace_ settings, both other settings, Project or User, show _Unable to load ..._

Comment: I added `--ignore E501` to the autopep8 parameters. And can live with that. But I now will start a new thread on the interpreter issue